# Do an operation with paste0 in a loop

Tags: r

I’m trying to do this action in loop:

```
library(data.table)

dc_clean202211 <- dc_clean202211[, .SD[.N], by="id_call"]
```

To start I read RDS files like this:

```
file_list <- list(202211,202210,202209,202208,202207,202206,202205,202204,202203,202202,202201,202112)
for (i in file_list){
#On crée un object par fichier
assign(paste0("dc_clean", i),readRDS(paste0("data/dc_clean", i , ".RDS")))
assign(paste0("dc_clean", i), paste0("dc_clean", i)[, .SD[.N], by="id_call"])
}
```

But I want to do my request in first row in my loop (or in another).

I tried a lot of possibilities but idk how to do this.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code? Do you get an error or something? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yeah sry I change my code with the problem

Comment: To get the value of a variable from a string, use `get()`. `assign(paste0("dc_clean", i), get(paste0("dc_clean", i))[, .SD[.N], by="id_call"])` But if you r are new to R, I strongly suggest avoiding get/assign. Things are much easier if you store values in named lists and apply transformation functions to those lists rather than creating a bunch of global variables with data embedded in the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one of two options, assuming that the numbers are similarly structured.

1. Put all frames into a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227), so that any operation you do to one can be easily extended to all with the simple use of `lapply`.

   ```r
   alldat <- lapply(setNames(nm = files), function(z) readRDS(paste0("data/dc_clean", z, ".RDS")))
   ## or perhaps more succinctly
   alldat <- lapply(setNames(paste0("data/dc_clean", files, ".RDS"), files), readRDS)
   ```

   `names(alldat)` should be the file names, for easy referencing.

   Your follow-on code than then be:

   ```r
   lapply(alldat, function(DT) DT[,. SD[, .N], by = "id_call"])
   ```

   to see the number of rows per `id_call` per file.
2. Put all frames into *one frame*, optionally preserving the name from which it was imported. Since we already read in all of the `.rds` files, we can simply row-bind them with:

   ```r
   alldat1 <- rbindlist(alldat, idcol = "filename")
   ```

   There are a few caveats:

   - If there are columns present in some that are not present in all, then you need to add `fill=TRUE`, and those columns will have `NA` values where they did not exist in the original file;
   - If the order of columns is not identical (or there are some present/missing), then I also suggest adding `use.names=TRUE`;
   - All classes should match. That is, column `A` must always be the same class as all the other frame's column `A`. `rbindlist` can deal with simpler issues, demonstrated by

   ```r
   rbindlist(list(data.table(a=1), data.table(a=2L))) # numeric and integer
   #        a
   #    <num>
   # 1:     1
   # 2:     2
   rbindlist(list(data.table(a=1), data.table(a="2"))) # numeric and character
   #         a
   #    <char>
   # 1:      1
   # 2:      2
   ```

   but if there is ambiguity or uncertainty, I suggest you verify your columns before moving too far further.

   With this, you can do

   ```r
   alldat1[, .SD[,.N], by = .(filename, id_call)]
   ```

   for the same basic results (notice the addition of `filename` to the `by=` argument).